# Undefined variable: data_test in view after upgrading laravel to 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

Collegues

I upgraded laravel from 5.3 to 5.7

very strange situation....

I pass variable from one view to another partial view:

**lead.blade.php**

```
<div class="container lead_items">
    <div class="row">
        @include('parts.post', ['data_test' => 'hello'])

    </div>
</div>
```

**parts/post.blade.php**

```
<?php echo $data_test; ?>
```

I get error: **Undefined variable: data_test (View: /home/vagrant/Code/jurnal/resources/views/parts/post.blade.php)**

If I change post.blade.php to:

```
<?php echo $data_test; die; ?>
```

I get output value 'hello'

Explain me please why variable is not defined.

Comment: you can try with this `<?php echo $data_test ?? ""; ?>`

Comment: Why Undefined variable: data_test? Why?